# mongoose / mongodb date save castError

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I am getting this error when just getting a document from the database and then immediately saving it. It is accepted on the initial insert though, and looks like the date fields are empty even though they are required.

{ stack: [Getter/Setter],
    message: 'Cast to date failed for value "[object Object]"',
         name: 'CastError',
     type: 'date',
     value: 
       { millisecond: 0,
         second: 0,
         minute: 0,
         hour: 0,
         day: 21,
         week: 38,
         month: 8,
         year: 2011 } }

This is the schema and query code that fails:

```
var Event = new Schema({
    id     : { type: String, index: true }
  , msg      : { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true }
  , triggerOn      : { type: Date, required: true }
  , createdOn       : { type: Date, required: true }
  , triggered       : { type: Boolean, required: true }
});

exports.pullAndUpdateTest = function(){
    var Model = mongoose.model('Event');
    Model.find({ triggered: false }, function (err, docs) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
    }
    docs.forEach(function(doc, index, array){
        //date both appear to be null here
               console.log(doc.triggerOn);  //=> null / prints blank
        console.log(doc.createdOn); //=> null / prints blank

        doc.triggered = true;
        doc.save(function(err){ console.log(err)});
    });
});
}
```

Comment: also found [this](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/502) exact issue that was never resolved

Comment: Latest version of mongoose fixes this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date.js is a very cool library, however the default implementation will create a mess in Node.js applications when working with MongoDB. I'd recommend you to use [safe_datejs](https://github.com/firebaseco/safe_datejs). You will be able to use Date.js function but you're gonna have to convert the `Date` values to a Date.js object before calling any of the Date.js magical functions.

Example:

```
var safe_datejs = require('safe_datejs');
var today = new Date();
var unsafeToday = today.AsDateJs(); // Converting to Date.js object
var unsafeTomorrow = unsafeToday.clone().add({days:1}); // Work with Date.js a little
var tomorrow = unsafeTomorrow.AsRegularDate(); //converted back safe to be used with MongoDB
```

To change culture specific attributes, use `safe_datejs.DateType.CultureInfo`

More info: https://github.com/firebaseco/safe_datejs

Comment: Date.js is actually pretty good about preserving the original Date model whilst adding additional behaviour.  The problem is that Mongoose currently skips type checking whenever it finds a toObject method on an object.  There's a pull request pending to correct that: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/646.

Answer (score 1):

This will occur if you have datejs required anywhere in your application (or use any module that, in turn, requires datejs).

Comment: No longer true - latest versions of mongoose are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your model with mongoose?

```
var Model = mongoose.model('Event', Event);
```